# pip install python-libtorrent==1.1.0 fails on linux

Tags: python, libtorrent

Title is self explanatory. I get the following error in linux and python2.7:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-libtorrent (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-libtorrent
```

I can see it listed on pypi:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libtorrent/

so, why would it not install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package in question, and its version, has been registered to PyPI. However there is no downloadable distribution file at all. Either the author/maintainer forgot to upload it (or them), or it was later removed.

If a distribution was uploaded, it should show up on the [1.1.0 release page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libtorrent/1.1.0); there should be a table that lists all distribution files, their formats, Python version, upload date and the size of that individual file. Compare with say (just a random linked package) [PyTorrent-0.1.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyTorrent/0.1.1) that has an .egg binary distribution file `PyTorrent-0.1.1-py2.5.egg` in there.

Comment: It seems like this is not a priority for the project owner: https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/319

Comment: @NegatioN they're talking about binary releases, but the problem is that there are absolutely no files for 1.1.0, binary, source, windows, macos - nothing, nada, zip.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a old post but for those who are problem like missing module, it's just a Python bindings for "libtorrent-rasterbar". First install this package using your package-manager and you can install this module. Or it may already be installed with the package.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you also include a link from where to get the bindings/package

Comment: You shouldn't need links. Once you download the "libtorrent-rasterbar" using your distro package manager, you can just "pip install python-libtorrent" to successfully install the module.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this error during installation of `stable-baselines3`, try this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/carlosluis/stable-baselines3@fix_tests
```